# Jenkins SBT plugin: How to have no tests being run treated as success?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I am building an SBT project on Jenkins with the SBT plugin, which works fine so far. The goals I execute are `compile testQuick`. This causes Jenkins to only run tests affecting things that changed since the last Git Push.

However, when I only reorganize things in my build files or bump a version number, this causes no tests to be run, and the post-build action "Publish JUnit test results" to fail.

Is there a way to treat no tests being run as a success instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but a makeshift workaround until anyone comes up with a better idea:

I created a "dummy test result file" `dummyresult.xml` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="DummyResultSoBuildDoesNotFail" errors="0" tests="0" failures="0" time="0" timestamp="2013-05-24T10:23:58" />
   <testsuite name="DummyResultSoBuildDoesNotFail.constructor" errors="0" skipped="1" tests="1" failures="0" time="0.006" timestamp="2013-05-24T10:23:58">
      <properties>
         <property name="java.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc." />
         <property name="compiler.debug" value="on" />
         <property name="project.jdk.classpath" value="jdk.classpath.1.6" />
      </properties>
      <testcase classname="DummyResultSoBuildDoesNotFail.constructor" name="Dummy result, needed so result collection does not fail" time="0">
         <skipped />
      </testcase>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Then I added a post build step which is "Execute shell" and executes the following:

```
mkdir -p target/test-reports && cp ~/dummyresult.xml target/test-reports
```

Now, even when no tests are run, Jenkins picks up one skipped "Dummy test" and is happy.